# When coding with python and tkinter I use column and row to seperate the labels but they are seperating too far

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I put the player names into column 1, but then when i put MP(Matches Played) into column 2 it moves way too far across how do i make it so that they are a lot closer and not so far apart.

````
root = Tk()
#Labels
lblTitle = Label(text="Chelsea FC Player Statistics",font=('bold', 15), fg="blue",).grid(row=0, column=2)
#Player Names Labels
lblPlayerNames = Label(text="Player Names",font=('bold')).grid(row=1, column=1)
lblDK = Label(text="Daniel Keelagher").grid(row=2, column=1)
lblJK = Label(text="Joseph Keelagher").grid(row=3, column=1)
lblBM = Label(text="Benjamin Miller").grid(row=4, column=1)
lblJT = Label(text="Jordan Terlato").grid(row=5, column=1)

#Matches Played Labels
lblMatchesPlayed = Label(text="MP",font=('bold')).grid(row=1, column=2)
lblDKMatches = Label(text="10").grid(row=2, column=2)
lblDKMatches = Label(text="9").grid(row=3, column=2)
lblDKMatches = Label(text="9").grid(row=4, column=2)
lblDKMatches = Label(text="8").grid(row=5, column=2)```
````

Comment: Put `lblTitle` in column 1 and add `columnspan=2` to `.grid(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

The widget `ibltitle` is bigger and it increases the width of your column 2.
And then all the widgets you put in column 2 will be center aligned below `ibltitle`.
You should put the `ibltitle` in column 1 and then set it's `columnspan` to 2.
Sorry for my bad formatting as I am new to Stackoverflow.

Comment: If this worked for you plese prefer upvoting this answer.